# Dynamic attribute starting with a name "Jquery" for input elements in a form

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I have added jQuery library to my `SP2010` custom master page and did few functionalities. Everything works fine. But when I open the native sharepoint pages, the form elements seems to have an extra attribute with a name starting with `jquery` followed by a unique id.
I don't understand what this is and how to prevent this.

```
<input name="DisplayName" title="Column name:" class="ms-input" id="idColName" type="text" size="30" maxLength="255" jQuery16408311599178054088="1" value="Article Date"/>
```

Please let me know how can avoid the form elements getting added with such attributes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

It is a cache key (expando attribute). This happens almost only on IE and it occurs when you bind events to the element. This is a core portion of events in jquery and comes with the framework and I don't think you can disable that.